Determine the type of equilibrium point
My system is
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= -x+y+y^2 \\
\dot{y} &= x y
\end{align}
and the question is to determine the type of equilibrium point in $(0,0)$.
First of all, I don't think this can be easily classified since linearization gives an eigenvalue equal to zero. So I guess the question is about the stability of the eq. point.
To determine stability I have tried to find a first integral, without success. I have also drawn general velocity vectors in the phase plane for all sections that are separated by the isoclines for $\dot{x}=0$ and $\dot{y}=0$. This is also inconclusive. Then I tried transforming into polar coordinates and using the blow-up technique. This also doesn't seem to work.
As a next step I could perhaps to try to prove (in)stability by the definition of (in)stability, but I'd rather stay away from extensively rigorous and potentially ugly epsilon/delta proofs. Any help?

If you start on $y=x$ you stay there.

@Empy2 yes of course! This is enough for me to show that (0,0) is unstable I think. Thank you!

More generally, in directions with $0 < x \le y, (\dot x, \dot y)$ points away from $(0,0)$.

Hint.
From $\dot y = x y = y_x \dot x = y_x(-x+y+y^2)$ and making $y = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ we can find a central manifold as $y = x$ which is unstable.
